# Does BF4 Premium carry over from PC to PS4?

Tags: pc, battlefield-4, ps4

I bought Premium for Battlefield 4 on PC. I was wondering if I bought a PS4 with Battlefield 4 will my Premium carry over from PC?

Answer (score 6):

No, Premium does not carry over. You will have to buy premium again or just not buy it at all.